# Neo4j Server Plugin

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am starting with Neo4j server plugin and browsing java APIs.
I found that `Node` is a sub-interface which extends `property-container`. But which class implements 'Node' class ?

What kind of magic is happening here ?

Any help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should not rely on any implementation details. The contract is the `Node` interface - as long as you rely on this, you're pretty much safe when upgrading your application to a newer version of Neo4j.

In most case a Node reference is implemented using `org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy`.